# Javascript force open a link in a browser

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to do object detection from JavaScript and force open a link in a specific browser?

For eg: **Open in IE, Open in Firefox**

Answer (score 6):

No. Definitely not without some browser plugin. This would be a huge security risk if it were possible.