# Javascript code to open URL in default Browser

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript force open a link in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494644/javascript-force-open-a-link-in-a-browser)

I am working on a code which specifically runs on Internet Explorer only.

Scenario is

I have a link in that IE browser which says "Preview". Whenever clicked on it, the link opens in Internet Explorer only.

I want the link to open in Client's Default Web Browser and not IE.

Working Environment is:
Language Used is HTML with JS, JQUERY and PHP as coding language.

Comment: "_Right Click is disabled in secure browser._" - I'll bet it's not as secure as you think it is.

Comment: I cant talk about security. Just want to know how can i open the link in default browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725645/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-javascript-link-open-up-in-ie?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494644/javascript-force-open-a-link-in-a-browser?rq=1 . The short answer is: No.

Comment: I dont know why are we more concerned about secure word. concern is to open in default browser

Comment: @AbhishekSanghvi security is a concern because based on what you've described, it doesn't seem secure at all.

Comment: I have edited the question to reduce the confusion. I hope now its more clear..

Comment: If I'm viewing a site in a web browser, I'd like the links to open up in *that* web browser.  Not open another one.

Comment: @AbhishekSanghvi Did you create the code that only runs in IE or is it 3rd party code? If it's your code, couldn't you just change it to run in all browsers?

Comment: @Rocket I agree to the point that the link should not open up in other web browser but thats the requirement given to me.

Comment: @AbhishekSanghvi: "Requirement?"  Can you explain *why* you need to do this?  Because it's impossible.

Comment: @AbhishekSanghvi As I previously mentioned, you already have your answer. The answer is that it's impossible. Tell your manager/boss that it's impossible to do and you'll have to think of another way. We'll guide you to a work-around if you tell us what exactly you need this for, and why you've previously done it the way that you have.

Comment: @Rocket Thanks for the info. I also did lot of search about it and then finally came to stackoverflow. I will stop with the code right now.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks i will inform about it and stop working on it for time being

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that is controlled at the OS level and not JavaScript. And as the comments to your post say, this is just a bad idea.